# Exchange hybrid - 404 REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to access an on-premise Exchange mailbox using the Microsoft Graph REST API as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support

I have Exchange 2016 configured in hybrid mode and synced to Office 365.

This setup worked for several days - I could read on-premise mailboxes by sending REST requests https://graph.microsoft.com. It suddenly stopped working on Dec. 1.

Currently, I can perform the Oauth2 flow, but when sending an API request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`
I get this 404 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI",
        "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox."
    }
}
```

When using Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) on the same mailbox, the API works as expected, i.e. no error and I can read the mailbox contents.
So it doesn't seem like any problem in the hybrid configuration itself.
On top of that, using the access token generated by Graph Explorer in Postman works as well.

I've compared the tokens using https://jwt.ms and couldn't find any differences except for one-time internal values. I used the following scope in the Oauth request: `openid profile User.Read email Mail.Read`

Any ideas? I'm aware that on-premise REST API is in preview, but has Microsoft dropped this feature? It worked fine until the beginning of the month.
It seems that perhaps Graph Explorer, as a Microsoft app, has some special authorization, but I doubt that's the case.

Edit:
I compared the tokens generated by the oauth request in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), between the graph explorer and my Azure Apps (I tried several). Aside from timestamps, the different values are the app id, values which according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)
are one-time values. The values are: `nonce`, `aio`, `uti`, `rh`, `sub` (under `xms_st`)

Comment: Does it happens only for specific API calls or for all the API calls which are in supported list?

Comment: I specifically use the /messages endpoint, which being part of Mail should work, and has worked fine in this setup up until a week ago. Other mail endpoints give the same error. "/me" for getting the profile works. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717133/ms-graph-api-return-errors-for-hybrid-integration-only-on-some-ips), in my case since the problem started, the request still always succeeds if I use a token obtained by graph explorer. I suppose I could try running the oauth flow from a server on a different region.

Comment: Whatif you setup a new oAuth application/call with POSTMAN with same flow/permissions setup of stuff that you do with Graph Explorer? Does it work or fails?

Comment: When using Postman, OAuth succeeds and any API requests using the token fail. I tried both authorization code and implicit flows (Graph explorer seems to be using implicit). I even tried carrying over some query parameters that graph explorer is using. The access tokens are nearly identical between the apps except for the app id and name (and values such as nonce). This behavior is consistent for the past week.

Comment: I went over the [token documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens), the values which differ between the tokens are classified as internal, and there's one value which is different and isn't documented: `xms_st`

Comment: Ok, let me dig this further.

Comment: One more difference I noticed is that the Graph Explorer app is [verified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/mark-app-as-publisher-verified), and the apps I use aren't from a verified publisher.

Comment: Verified/unverified publisher should not make any difference here. If its working for the same API calls with Graph Explorer (using that you can access Azure AD delegated permissions only and not application permissions will work) then it should work with other application till the time you use the same Azure AD workflow & delegated permissions.

Comment: Graph explorer works using Authcode flow, so you may want to try setting and see if it helps you moving forward.

Comment: @Dev I tried both Authorization Code and Implicit flows. Both succeed in creating a token, and when sending a request to the endpoint it fails with 404. I also tried several auth URLs: common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize and {tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Comment: hmm.. that's sad. I see your comment whether the feature is dropped or not; if there is one, there would be an announcement, but i failed to find one - so the older recommendation stays the same.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you checked both tokens at https://jwt.ms/ maybe there is just something wrong with the token. You can easily verify at that website.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, I  used jwt.ms and mentioned it before. The only significant differences are the app id (which is expected) and the xms_st.sub value From reading the documentation that's the user id unique for the application, so it's also expected. I'll edit my original question and add this.

Comment: In order to eliminate this as a cause, I created a verified app, and still getting 404.